# load new page in modal(ajax), while using pushState to change URI

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I am trying load new content (login/thread create/thread view/quick search) within a pop-up window/modal, but change the URI as well using pushState.

Now, I have the general concept down, but am slightly confused on the exact mechanics.

I was browsing sites and came across www.usatoday.com/news.  I did some research and it appears they use pushState to change the URI and load content via AJAX in a modal window.

My question involves specifically how to pull and display the 'new page' within the modal window.  Its clear you will need to have a new controller to display the correct URI and make it shareable/crawlable.  But is it possible to take that page and display it directly in a modal?  Or do you have to cheese the information in a completely new ajax-driven model/view?

Answer (score 1):

what modal are you using? If for example you are using fancybox. You just give the anchor link to your page an additional class of fancybox and the page is opened in a modal, all the ajax is handled for you. You can then add your code for pushstate in the aftershow callback function of the fancybox.

There is also an after close callback, where you would popstate or push a new state to revert the uri back to is original state.

How you handle someone entering the uri externally is up to you. But id you have already built the page as a standalone link then it shouldn't be a problem. if you wanted it to open in the fancybox though you would have to init the fancybox on doc ready for that page.

Also you said that it is clear you would have to have a new controller for this. That is not true at all, in fact I would not have a separate controller at all, if I was you I would define a constant as follows in constants.php:

```
define('IS_AJAX', isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) == 'xmlhttprequest');
```

You can then just do a check like the following:

```
if (!IS_AJAX){
    //here is code for non ajax page load, e.g load headers, footers etc that you dont need in ajax requests etc.
}else{
    //often dont need this but if you have code specifically for ajax call put it here
}
```

}

Comment: Thanks.  I actually just downloaded colorbox.  It works, but I am still having trouble figuring out how to pass data correctly. For instance, if they user searches, I pass their search through a GET in the URL( ?q=search ).  How would I retrieve that data using colorbox/fancybox?

Comment: You can process your uri server side in exactly the same way that you would with a non-ajax request. Have a go, if you are having trouble post some code and specific details of the problems you are having. If you start a new question, put a link here and I will take a look for you.

Comment: Thanks, I will work on a new question. In them mean time. You said that a new controller isn't necessary.  If thats the case, for instance, how would the user be able to save as favorite a specific search?  Or additionally, if I had a link to a thread (www.xyz.com/thread/123-this-thread/), how could I change pushstate, load this page, and have them be able to save as favorite or share the link.

Comment: see this link for code and more specific question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14321797/sending-data-through-link-using-colorbox-ajax. Thanks!